# About the ε-δ argument

Tags: limits, analysis, epsilon-delta

I want to confirm the logic within the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument when proving the limit exists. When we are proving $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=L$ is true, we are actually trying to prove a "if-then" statement: $ \exists L\in \mathbb R, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta >0,\forall x\in domf : 0<|x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-L|< \epsilon $. Is this correct

Then when proving the "if-then" statement is true. We use a property of the "if-then" statement, which is if this "if-then" statement is true, then assume the "if" part is true, then the "then” part must be true. (i.e. if $0<|x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-L|< \epsilon $ is true, then if  $ 0<|x-a|<\delta $ is true, $|f(x)-L|< \epsilon $ must be true.

Then because $ a $ is a limit point of $ domf$ then the "if" part is always true(we don't even need to assume it is true). Therefore, we need to test whether the $ |f(x)-L|< \epsilon $ is
true.

However, we test $|f(x)-L|< \epsilon $ part by using a slightly inverse method. Because we know the $ 0<|x-a|<\delta $ is always true(we can find any positive number to be our $ \delta $, therefore, we're trying to find a "suitable" $ \delta $ within all positive numbers to make then part :$ |f(x)-L|< \epsilon $ be true.  That's why we always firstly calculate $|f(x)-L|< \epsilon $ this part, then make a suitable $ \delta $ value.

My question is what parts in my above words are wrong, or do I misunderstand something? Thank you!

Comment: The "must be true" part is not right. What the $0<|x-a|<\delta$ condition is doing here is forcing us to restrict attention to $x$'s that are near $a$, not random far away $x$'s for which we have no reason to believe $f(x)$ should be close to $f(a)$. But we do indeed need to find $\delta$ depending on $\epsilon$ (and in the case of continuity on $a$ also) that is "close enough" that $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Yeah. I'm still confused a little bit. I'm trying to link this logic with the induction proof because when doing induction, we also prove an "if-then" statement. We always assume the $$ A(n) $$ is correct, then we check $$ A(n+1) $$.  On the other hand, at this point, we don't need to assume $ 0<|x-a|<\delta $ is correct because it is always correct due to $ a $ being the limit point of the domain. Therefore, all we need to do is to "check" $ |f(x)-f(a)|< \epsilon $. However, because we can turn $f(x)$ into a thing that is related to $x$, we can do things inversely. Is this a correct idea?

Comment: $f(a)$ is not necessarily well-defined even when the limit exists; e.g., $$f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}, \quad x \ne 0$$ is not defined at $x = 0$ yet the limit exists.  Therefore, you cannot write $|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$.  Instead, you must write $$|f(x) - L| < \epsilon.$$

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you

Comment: Your statement of the definition is missing a $\forall x$ somewhere. As it stands, it is a claim that can have different truth values for each pair of $x$ and $a$; that is not how limits work.

Comment: What the condition is doing is restricting the $x$'s that we're talking about. This should indeed have a third quantifier on the inside over $x$ (as it is the truth value depends on $x$ which it shouldn't).